# Удалить метку [data]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки

Зачем нам метка [data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data)? Не вижу в ней никакого смысла, она совершенно безлика. Очень похожа на метаметку, так как всё программирование и не только связано с данными. По ней довольно немало (92) вопросов, поэтому лучше бы удаление было бы автоматическим.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Одного удаления мало, рано или поздно она будет создана кем-то снова. Надо запретить её на уровне настроек сайта, как это сделано на enSO:

> [image: data is not allowed]

Comment: Kill it with fire!