# Опубликовать список запрещённых меток

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

[Недавний вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7035/176217) о метке [data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) натолкнул на мысль, что было бы неплохо иметь возможность лицезреть список уже запрещённых на сайте меток (без использования *reverse-engineering*). А также предоставить участникам возможность редактировать этот список, по большей части в плане добавления новых меток. Но в редких ситуациях может быть и с возвратом какой-либо метки в список разрешённых, если она, например, досталась в наследство от некоторого базового подмножества англоязычного сайта и в русскоязычной версии её существование имеет смысл быть.

Если сама идея будет поддержана сообществом, то впоследствии упомянутый список стоит собрать совместными усилиями, как это, например, было сделано в ситуации с [автоматическим вырезанием приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6667/176217). Для получения исходного состояния, как я понимаю, без сотрудников компании не обойтись. Вроде бы только они имеют прямой доступ к списку запрещённых меток, и простым модератором он недоступен.

Comment: Надо еще добавить метку `списки`!

Comment: @FoggyFinder и `быстро!`

Comment: @FoggyFinder и добавить её в список запрещённых меток. Мета!

Comment: Пожалуй, самый адекватный формат, где не было бы рассинхронки — это запрос sede. Также возможность редактирования этого списка модераторами очень была бы кстати.

Comment: Я полагал, что *все* сжигания и запрещения меток проходят через мету и находятся по меткам [удаление-метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) и [чёрный-список-меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA). Запрещать/разрешать ту или иную метку без публичного обсуждения мне кажется неправильным, неважно делают ли это сотрудники, бубновые модераторы или рядовые участники.

Comment: @defaultlocale так мы на Мете здесь как раз.

Comment: @alexolut Насколько я понял из Вашего вопроса, какие-то метки были запрещены без обсуждения (и [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA) их нет), что меня несколько удивило.

Comment: @defaultlocale как минимум, это доставшиеся в наследство [метки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298299/339911). Может есть и ещё, поэтому-то и хочется видеть список.

Comment: @alexolut стало яснее, спасибо за пример по ссылке. От себя предложил бы очистить этот список и разбираться с метками по одной через мету.

Comment: @defaultlocale лучше публикуйте идеи в секции ответов, метка [meta-tag:обсуждение] тут как раз для этих целей.

Comment: @alexolut А может вы лучше предложите такое на главной мете? Я с радостью проголосую "за" и, возможно, другие тоже. Я бы не отказался от такой функциональности на каждом сайте.